# Radius of Convergence for Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, power-series

I have to find the radius of convergence for this one, but I haven’t found a solution for this type of a term.

$\mathbb f (x)$ = $1 + 7x^3 + 5x^4 + x^{13} + x^{2015}$

Could you help me out?

Comment: It's a finite sum, it can't not converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a finite sum, this one converges for every $x \in \Bbb C$, so its radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: So finite sums always have the radius of convergence $\infty$?

Comment: @Questionnaire: Always. Think of them as $\sum a_n x^n$ where all $a_n = 0$ for $n \ge n_0$. Intuitively then, $\sqrt [n] {|a_n|} = 0$ for $n \ge n_0$ and the radius of convergence is $\frac 1 0 = \infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Pardon the bad English, but I struggle with this to and the comment above doesn't helped me to totally demonstrate the situation, so here is a more complete answer to anyone who has to demonstrate the radius of convergence for a polynomial.

What happens to the nth derivative of your function when n is greater than one plus your biggest exponent? all are 0.

So, you can write the polynomial as your polynomial plus the sum from 0 to infinity of your nth derivative of your function over n factorial times $(x-a)^n$ where a is your center.
Since the nth derivative at this point are all equal, you're multiplying a constant, so you can bring to the outside of the sum that constant (property of sums) and now you can make any test to show that the radius of convergence is infinite.